# Appium+Selenium Android: ListView item not clicked without Thread.sleep

Tags: android, selenium, selenium-webdriver, automated-tests, appium

I hate using "sleepers" `(Thread.sleep(millis)`) in tests, but without sleepers some tests fail.

I have a `ListView` in my `Android` application and I want to tap on the first item in the list (SAUDI ARABIA in our case).

[image: Countries ListView]

```
 public AndroidDriver androidDriver;
 ...
 androidDriver = new AndroidDriver(serverAddress, capabilities);
 androidDriver.manage().timeouts().implicitlyWait(30, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
 driverWait = new WebDriverWait(androidDriver, 30);
 // at this moment everything is initialized and working properly,
 // Appium server is up and running
 driverWait.until(ExpectedConditions.visibilityOfElementLocated(By.id("com.###.debug:id/countries_list_view")));
 WebElement countriesList = driver.findElement(By.id("com.###.debug:id/countries_list_view"));
 List<WebElement> countries = countriesList.findElements(By.id("com.###.debug:id/list_item_container"));
 WebElement country = countries.get(0);
 // country isn't null, and it corresponds to a real ListView row
 driverWait.until(ExpectedConditions.elementToBeClickable(country));
 Thread.sleep(1000); // <---- country isn't clicked without this
 country.click();
```

The same problem exists in `Calabash/Cucumber` tests (explicit waits required).

I've tried different ways of waiting for the element which should be clicked

- `driverWait.until(ExpectedConditions.visibilityOfElementLocated(By));`
- `driverWait.until(ExpectedConditions.visibilityOf(WebElement));`
- `driverWait.until(ExpectedConditions.elementToBeClickable(By));`
- `driverWait.until(ExpectedConditions.presenceOfElementLocated(By));`

and none is working. At the moment when I try to tap on the `ListView` 1st item, `ListView` exists and is all the list elements are on screen.

I've tried to find the `ListView` 1st row by getting the list row `XPath` using `Appium Inspector`. The result is the same - view isn't clicked without `Thread.sleep`.

Using `Thread.sleep` in tests is really bad practice and makes my tests unstable. I can't rely on tests results in this case, as they may fail even if the application is working properly. There's an article about "wait" and "sleep" usage in Selenium tests ([Selenium WebDriver wait](http://www.testingdiaries.com/selenium-webdriver-wait/)).

1. How to fix such issues in tests?
2. How often `Thread.sleep` calls used in automation world? (I'm mostly Android developer, and not that experienced in mobile automation).

**UPDATE:**
I've tried to not to mix up implicit and explicit waits, as [JeffC](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2386774/jeffc) mentioned, and it didn't help.

Here's my test:

```
@Test
public void selectCountryLanguageAndStartApplication() throws Exception {
    countryLanguagePage.loaded();
    countryLanguagePage.selectFirstCountry();
    countryLanguagePage.pleaseSelectCountryTextIsHidden();
    countryLanguagePage.startClick();
}
...
/**
 * Verify the page has loaded
 */
public static void loaded() {
    driver.findElement(By.id("com.###.debug:id/countries_list_view"));
}
```

I'm verifying if the page is loaded in every test. If I use only implicit waits - the test fails from time to time; if I use only explicit waits - it's the same, the test fails from time to time.

I've found in [Appium tutorial](https://github.com/appium/tutorial) that they use [implicit](https://github.com/appium/tutorial/blob/master/projects/java_android/src/test/java/appium/tutorial/android/util/AppiumTest.java#L112) in conjunction with explicit ones [1](https://github.com/appium/tutorial/blob/master/projects/java_android/src/test/java/appium/tutorial/android/util/Helpers.java#L131), [2](https://github.com/appium/tutorial/blob/master/projects/java_android/src/test/java/appium/tutorial/android/AutomatingASimpleActionTest.java#L21). It looks weird according to the [docs](http://www.seleniumhq.org/docs/04_webdriver_advanced.jsp).

The working solution: I've modified a bit `loaded` method

```
public static void loaded() {
   driver.findElement(By.id("com.###.debug:id/countries_list_view"));
    try {
        Thread.sleep(1000);
    } catch (InterruptedException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

Having that sleep brings the "stability" to test and I can find the elements and press on them with explicit waits or without them.

Does it mean, that I should add "sleep" when the new `Activity` launched (the only working solution to me)? Or I'm waiting for the Activity initialization in the wrong way?

Comment: `driverWait.until(ExpectedConditions.elementToBeClickable(element));` should this be `elementToBeClickable(country)` instead?

Comment: no. Please check "Selenium WebDriver wait" link from the post about explicit waits.

Comment: Okay, just checking. I haven't used selenium, but I have done some automated testing using Espresso for Android and I remember being recommended to turn off animations on the device in order for testing to work. The animations can cause issues with clicking list items. Have you tried doing that?

Comment: Yes, it's not fixing the problem.

Comment: I know I seem to be grasping at anything but why is `WebElement countriesList = driver.findElement(By.id());` blank? Shouldn't you add the id inside of those parens?

Comment: [According to the docs](http://www.seleniumhq.org/docs/04_webdriver_advanced.jsp), you should not mix implicit and explicit waits. I would start by removing the implicit wait and see if that helps.

Comment: Have you tried printing outerHTML for `country`, etc. and see what is going on in the HTML? Sometimes there are things that change in the HTML that you don't see when you look after the fact. I just had this happen in the last few days.

Answer (score 0):

You could try this:

```
  WebDriverWait wait = new WebDriverWait(driver, 30); 
  wait.until(ExpectedConditions.elementToBeClickable(By));
```

or

```
while(!driver.findElement(By).isDisplayed())
{
  //Thread.sleep(10);
}
```

I think `Thread.sleep` calls are fine to use (and almost necessary if your testing involves timing) but for the most part there a better ways to handle most things they would be used for.

Hope this helps,

Liam

Comment: I'm using conditional wait in my example, it's not working anyway.

Comment: Okay, you could use the `isDisplayed` method to force the test to wait until the element is displayed. Answer updated with example

Comment: I've tried to wait for element using `while`-solution, and the test fails occasionally. Before clicking on the element, I've printed his "isDisplayed" property, and it's true all the time, but test fails without touching the element :(

Comment: Very strange indeed, if this error is repeatable on other machines/other elements then maybe its time to head over to [Appium - Bugs and Issues](https://discuss.appium.io/c/issues-bugs)? What happens when you `Thread.sleep` after printing isDisplayed = true then try to click the element? And what is the result of `.getSize` and `.getText`?

Comment: Great idea. I don't think it's an Appium problem, it might be the mobile automation problem, as it's repeatable using Calabash/Cucumber stack also.

Comment: Yeah I agree. I would also try `.getSize`, as I imagine the result will either provide a workaround to the original problem or further highlight the issue

Answer (score 0):

I have Tried to write a method , to wait for an element. hope it will work for your case.

```
import io.appium.java_client.android.AndroidDriver;
import io.appium.java_client.android.AndroidElement;
import org.openqa.selenium.support.ui.ExpectedConditions;
import org.openqa.selenium.support.ui.WebDriverWait;

public class Utility {
    public static AndroidElement element;
    public  static  boolean isElementPresent;
    public static boolean waitForPresence(AndroidDriver driver, int timeLimitInSeconds, String targetResourceId){

        try{
            element =  (AndroidElement) driver.findElementByAndroidUIAutomator("new UiSelector().resourceId(\""+targetResourceId+"\")");
            WebDriverWait wait = new WebDriverWait(driver, timeLimitInSeconds);
            wait.until(ExpectedConditions.visibilityOf(element));
            isElementPresent = element.isDisplayed();
            return isElementPresent;
        }catch(Exception e){
            isElementPresent = false;
            System.out.println(e.getMessage());
            return isElementPresent;
        }
    }
}
```